# How do you set the current time in a plpython3u postgresql trigger?

Tags: postgresql, python-3.x, triggers

Found lots of information that had parts of solution, but not complete answer, so I thought I'd post it for future use. The postgres has examples of how to create a trigger and describes the TD array, so I won't repeat that here:

```
   n = datetime.datetime.now( )
   TD["new"]["updated_ts"] = n.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

Comment: But you might link to where *"The postgres has examples"* and provide some more context like your version of Postgres.

Comment: I could. And then three years from now a developer ends up going to an out of date or non-existent webpage. But if they google "how do I write a postgres python trigger," they're likely to get a reasonably good link, whether they do that today, next week, next year, or next decade.

Comment: If anybody should find this question in 3 years and your link should be dead by then, he can still google. Please provide a proper question if you like proper answers.